# new user interface update (SiteEdit) in Tridion 2011 SP1 is not working in IE 8 and 9

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

When we click on the SDL Tridion button in IE browser, it is redirecting to `servername/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Editor.aspx` with page not found message. But in Firefox it is working perfectly and Redirecting to `servername/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Editor.aspx#url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.view.mysite.com%2Findividual%2FnewUserInterfaceDemo%2Findex.html%23Basics`.

Please help me in this issue. Any configuration is there for IE browser?

Answer (score 6):

Reading the prerequisites for UI at ([http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/reference_339904289670453B90BED5AEB7258EB8](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/reference_339904289670453B90BED5AEB7258EB8%29) requires log in), IE8 is not supported anymore, so perhaps focus on IE9 for now..

Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? It looks like HTTPS, so you may need to sign the certificate as noted in this section of the documentation: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_A56C7DD930D14BAB9C2C30C40D29747A (also requires a log in)

Can you access the regular Content Manager Explorer with those browsers?

Try deleting **ALL** the cache in the browser including passwords etc, close it and try again.  This may be some kind of cached value causing your problem.

Answer (score 6):

I see your preview site is on `https`. Do you have proper SSL certificate installed. IE9 throws a warning if you have any self-signed or invalid certificate and does not let you continue further unless you accept the risk.

First, try on `http` and see if it is working with out https.

(OR)

Try loading the self-signed certificate to your IE 9 browser and check again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Thank You. I committed to the proposal. I have been trying to commit before but was unsuccessful, but when I followed the your link it went through. great.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing specific to Internet Explorer in the code, so something else is going on.

Please contact Customer Support instead for help on this issue, as it is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.